# How can I change form of headers in TabControl (TabPage)?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I need to change it from this:

[image]

to that:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with System.Windows.Forms.TabControl, you'll either have to live with the ones that VS gives you, create your own custom control that overrides the render of the tabcontrol, or download a theme that does this for you.